# How can I keep a single HTTP session alive?

Tags: http, http-headers, timeout, keep-alive

I'm working on a CGI script that will collect documents into an eBook and make that eBook easier to download.

Creating the eBook can take a few seconds, and it has timed out for some inputs for me in the past.

Is there any way I can / should keep the session alive so it doesn't time out?

Would it be helpful to add a made-up HTTP header like `X-Keep-Session-Alive` and periodically add a character to the header's value? (`Connection: keep-alive` looks like a superficially similar solution to a different problem, though I would not be completely surprised if it had something to offer me.)

(What would an implementation look like if there's anything that would do what I want?)